# Nginx default handler

Tags: nginx, devops, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm having trouble with configuring the nginx config. Here's my current conf:

```
server {
        listen        80;
        server_name   dev.local sat.local;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://sat:80;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

Now I want all requests to my host other than `dev.local` and `sat.local` will be passed to `https://prod:80` like this

```
server {
        listen        80;
        server_name   *;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://prod:80;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

Can we do it? And how can we do it? Please help.

Comment: Try: `listen 80 default_server;` and remove the `server_name  *;` line. See [these catch-all server examples](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, thanks to Richard Smith's answer.

```
server {
    listen       80  default_server;
    server_name  _;
}
```